# Combine two rows into one in Redshift [SQL]

Tags: amazon-redshift

How do I combine this result set in SQL(redshift env't):

| ID | Flag? | Plan? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MX_123 | 0 | 1 |
| MX_123 | 1 | 0 |
| MX_456 | 1 | 0 |
| MX_456 | 0 | 1 |

TO BECOME **THIS**

| ID | Flag? | Plan? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| MX_123 | 1 | 1 |
| MX_456 | 1 | 1 |

Comment: Can't you use aggregate function sum(flag),sum(plan) and group by id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for these suggestions. Was able to figure it out with an aggregate MAX(function) and using a subquery

```
SELECT a.id,
    ,max(a.flag)
    ,max(a.plan)
    from 
    (
        SUBQUERY HERE - has the dupes
    ) a
    group by a.id
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select id, sum(flag), sum(plan) from table group by id;
```

but if you can have non-distinct triplets there and want to have max 1, then I'd say something like:

```
SELECT
    id,
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(flag)>0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END, 
    CASE
        WHEN SUM(plan)>0 THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END
FROM table 
GROUP BY id;
```